The :focused pseudo-class does not work (CSS/JavaFX)
I'm making an application in JavaFX and using MFXTextField, which is part of the MaterialFX library. The task is to make the floating-text change color when the field is activated. I tried using the css pseudo-classes :focus and :focused, but it doesn't work. However, interestingly, the pseudo-class :pressed works
Here's what doesn't work:
.mfx-text-field .floating-text{
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}


.mfx-text-field:focused .floating-text {
    -fx-text-fill: -primary-color;
}


Works (but i don't need it):
.mfx-text-field .floating-text{
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}


.mfx-text-field:pressed .floating-text {
    -fx-text-fill: -primary-color;
}

The question is why might :focused not work?

did you try :focus-within ?

It works!!! Thank you!!!

glad i could help :)

Instead of :focused use :focus-within
